# How to implement a basic query management and recommendation system

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, recommender-system, similar-documents

I'm trying to prototype a system where given a textual query (e.g. a question), I get a list of most relevant documents/questions among a pool of available documents/questions (similar to what we see here in Stack Exchange when submitting a question).

One simple idea coming to my mind is to extract `important` keywords from query, and do matching based on keywords. Or any other ways, maybe through machine learning or data mining approaches.

I am very new to data science, and I believe this is a very basic system. Is there any available light-weight open source project on this? If not, any hints how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html) project to see if it is a good fit.

Comment: Looks very good. Is it open source?

Comment: Indeed it is open source.

Comment: Yeah, it's Apache. I'm a fan of Apache platforms!